# Unexpected behaviour of posedge event in case of x-transition

Tags: verilog

I have a design in which my clock makes a transition from 1 to x which is triggering @posedge clk event but according to LRM 1 to x should trigger negedge event.

So i tried this on simple d-flip flop & it is behaving similarly. Here is the code of d-flip/flop i have used for simulation.

```
module dff (clk,d,q);
input clk,d;
output q;
reg q;
always @(posedge clk) begin
q <= d;
end
endmodule
```

Here is my testbench

```
module tb_dff();
reg clk,d;
wire q;
reg clk_int,en;
dff U1 (.clk(clk),.d(d),.q(q));

initial  begin 
clk_int = 0;
forever #5 clk_int = ~clk_int;
end

always @(*) begin
clk = en ? 1'bx :clk_int ; 
end

initial begin
d <= 1'b1 ; en <= 1'b0;
@ (posedge clk);
@ (posedge clk);
#5
//clk 1-->x transition
d <= 1'b0 ; en <= 1'b1;
@ (posedge clk_int);
@ (posedge clk_int);
$stop;
end

endmodule
```

When i simulate the design.
When my clk goes from 1 to x, q gets the new value 1'b0.

Can you explain the behaviour?

Comment: Which simulator are you using?

Comment: @Morgan:cadence NCSIM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a zero-time glitch race condition between:

```
forever #5 clk_int = ~clk_int;
...
always @(*) clk = en ? 1'bx :clk_int ;
```

and

```
...
@(posedge clk);
#5;
en <= 1'b1;
...
```

The Verilog scheduler will update all scheduled blocking assignments before updating any non-blocking assignments. `en` is non-blocking, therefore `clk_int` and `clk` will be update before `en`. `clk` will be re-evaluated after the `en` update.

In zero time, `clk` transitions 1'b1->1'b0->1'bx, triggering `negedge` and `posedge` events.

Possible solutions:

- Reduce the delay before raising `en`. EX `#4`
- Assign `en` with a blocking assignment. (Works 98% of the time. Only potential issue is if the inputs also have glitches / race conditions)
- Use non-blocking assignment on `clk_int` or `clk` (*NOT RECOMMENCED!* Work in small designs but can create more glitches / race conditions. In large simulation this can add significant over head to scheduler with re-evaluations)

Answer (score 0):

I see the same results as you do on 2 simulators (NC and VCS).  If you change all your `posedge` to `negedge` in your testbench module, it should behave as you like:

```
initial begin
d <= 1'b1 ; en <= 1'b0;
@ (negedge clk);
@ (negedge clk);
#5
//clk 1-->x transition
d <= 1'b0 ; en <= 1'b1;
@ (negedge clk_int);
@ (negedge clk_int);
$stop;
end
```

In your testbench, you use blocking and nonblocking assignments and # delays and @ posedge in an ad hoc manner.